# How to Remove or Edit an SSL Certificate on a Digital Ocean OpenLiteSpeed Server

Tags: ssl

There is a LetsEncrypt SSL cert on a Digital Ocean OpenLiteSpeed sever I'm managing, which has the wrong name. Does anyone know if there is a way I can either remove the cert and make a new one or edit it? If I add a second cert with the correct information, does anyone know how that would play out? Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: You can't edit an SSL certificate. Off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, if you are applying the wrong domain or subdomain and you want to correct it so no need to correct it. change your SSL by using these steps :
**Open DigitalOcean Console** :

**Step1:** login with your username and password.

**Step2**: use this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot`

**Step 3:** command `sudo apt-get update`

**Step 4**: `sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache`

Now The certbot Let’s Encrypt client is now ready to use.

**Set Up the SSL Certificate**

**Step 5:** `sudo certbot --apache -d example.com` <<<<use your own domain or subdomain instead of example.com

**Verifying Certbot Auto-Renewal**

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

**If you want to delete SSL CERTBOT from your site use these commands:**

Command to Delete Certbot Certificate

```
$ sudo certbot delete
```

Delete Certbot Certificate by Domain Name

```
$ sudo certbot delete --cert-name example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

for removing ssl in digital ocean you can use

```
$ sudo certbot delete
```

there is no way to edit ssl becasue SSL is an encrypted format system.you can delete ssl from ssl or make a new ssl for your domain

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking about how to update the new LE cert on OpenLiteSpeed.

Basically you can follow this [official doc](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/wordpress/#optional-setup) to apply the cert and update the correct certificate & key path to the listener>SSL via web admin at port 7080.

Best